# If any two indices are equal, then the term is zero

Tags: abstract-algebra, homology-cohomology, sheaf-cohomology

Let $X$ be a topological space. Let $U_i$ be an open cover, with the index $i$ running through some set $I$. For $i_0$, $i_1$, ..., $i_n \in I$, write $U_{i_0 i_1 \cdots i_n}$ for $U_{i_0} \cap \cdots \cap U_{i_p}$. $\def\cE{\mathcal{E}}$Let $F$ be a sheaf of abelian groups on $X$ and $F_{i_0,i_1,...i_n}:=F(U_{i_0 i_1 \cdots i_n})$, we will write the group operation additively.

Let $I$ to be a set of indices, and $i_0, i_1, i_2... \in I$. For each array $(i_0,i_1,...i_n)$ associate a set $F_{i_0,i_1,...i_n}$ and take

$$(f_{\large i_0,i_1,...i_n})_{i_0,i_1,...i_n\in I}\in \prod_{\large i_0,i_1,...i_n}F_{\large i_0,i_1,...i_n}.$$

Define $d((f_{\large i_0,i_1,...i_n})_{\large i_0,i_1,...i_n\in I})=(\sum_{i=0}^{n+1}(-1)^kf_{\large i_0,...\hat{i_k},...i_{n+1}}|U_{i_0 i_1 \cdots i_{n+1}})_{\large i_0,i_1,...i_{n+1}\in I} $

I wonder if the following statement is true:

> Assume $d((f_{\large i_0,i_1,...i_n})_{\large i_0,i_1,...i_n\in I})=0$. If any two of the indices ${k_0,k_1,...k_n}$ are equal, then $f_{\large k_0,k_1,...k_n}=0$

---

See [here](http://www.its.caltech.edu/~pablos/files/AlgCurv-RS-Miranda.pdf#page=303#) for the description pf the cohomology w.r.t. an open cover and [this problem N](http://www.its.caltech.edu/~pablos/files/AlgCurv-RS-Miranda.pdf#page=313#) for the original question(from Rick Miranda's book).

I have made no constructive approach to this problem so far. One idea is to prove it backwards, first prove that it's zero when all of the indices are equal, then it is zero. But there will be an evenness-oddness problem.

---

Update:

I referred to the wrong problem earlier. It should be problem N.

Comment: Begin with $n=1$ and think how to generalize.

Comment: @N.H.  Yes, I have done the case $n=1$. And even $n=2$ is hard for me...

Comment: This basically mimics the proof of that for differential forms.

Comment: @user45765 Which proof? Could you show me some reference?

Comment: Your definition of $d$ doesn't make sense: what does $\sum_{i=0}^{n+1}(-1)^kf_{\large i_0,...\hat{i_k},...i_{n+1}}$ mean?  The terms are all elements of different sets, none of which are the set you want them to be in (and you haven't mentioned any abelian group structure).

Comment: In any case, I think David Speyer's answer to https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1269863/skew-symmetry-of-indices-in-cocycles-of-cech-cohomology probably answers what your actual question is.

Comment: @EricWofsey Okay, I see. There might be no convenient way to define it without involving the notions of sheaf theory... I will edit it

Comment: @EricWofsey So by "However, this is not the case for general p", David means he does believe this is true for $p>1$?

Comment: He means the answer to your question (rephrased in terms of sheaves so it makes sense) is no if $n>1$.

Comment: @EricWofsey Thank you very much! My previous "does" should be "doesn't"(a nonmathematical typo...)